# java.lang.classnotfoundexception com.mysql.jdbc.driver in ubuntu

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm getting a following error when the page is loaded. help me to find out this.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:128)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:66)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
at org.apache.jsp.create_jsp._jspService(create_jsp.java:1174)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Posiible Duplicate of [**All of These**](https://www.google.com/search?q=class%20dojo#q=classnotfoundexception%20mysql%20jdbc%20driver)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the `mysql` jdbc driver `jar` on your `classpath` ??

Comment: yes. in project_folder/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java.jar

Comment: which IDE you are using?

Comment: @Sarz i am not using any ide, i downloaded one open source tool on that need to change my db connection

Comment: Please put `<classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/lib/jdbc.jar"/>` in `.classpath` in your `project_name/.classpath`

Comment: @Sarz sorry i am using ubuntu machine

Answer (score 0):

Class is not accessible to JVM `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`, please make sure driver jar file  is added in your build path.

Answer (score 0):

Class is not accessible to JVM java.lang.ClassNotFoundException, please make sure it is added in your `tomcat lib folder and restart your tomcat server`

Since sometimes mysql jar is no longer a part from tomcat libs so you have to add it manually.

Particulary for mysql driver it's more confortable to add to tomcat libs folder inside of ../web-inf/lib